# Is it possible to reserve a hotel with a credit card with lower credit limit than the hotel expenses?

Tags: bookings, pre-pay

I am going to reserve a hotel by my credit card in booking.com. hotel expenses is more than 1600$ and my credit limit is 1000$. is it possible for me to reserve?
can I charge my credit card to 1600$ in advance (to prevent over limiting)?

I should say that my reservation dose not need to prepayment and is free cancellation.

Comment: The question on whether you can pay in to increase your credit line is something your specific credit card dictates, there is no universal rule.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about credit card terms and conditions, not about travel per se. (The answer would surely be the same if the asker wanted to spend $1600 on, e.g., a new computer.)

Answer (score 2):

This answer assumes the 1600$ covers more than a single night.

Details depend on the specific situation, but it is rather common that the credit card information is used to charge you for the first night in case you do not show up, then cancel the rest of the stay.  Then, when you actually pay for the hotel, you can use your debit card to pay.  If this is indeed the case, you should be fine using your 1000$ limit credit card.

Answer (score 1):

"Is it *possible* to reserve a hotel with a credit card with lower credit limit than the hotel expenses?"

**Yes**.  The most frequent scenarios are A) the hotel does not put any authorization hold on the card or B) puts a hold for one night as a guarantee.

You do not have to use the same card to settle the charges or authorize incidentals.

However, once you check-in, they may request a hold for all room nights unless you pay cash or make some other arrangement.

The only way to know for sure is to make the booking and contact the hotel 2-3 days later to confirm.  You can also check the card account to see what was done.